# CNN for single image camera calibration

Tags: keras, camera-calibration, imagenet

I've been reading a paper [A Perceptual Measure for Deep Single Image Camera Calibration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01259) where they adopt DenseNet with a last layer replaced by three separate heads.

I take DenseNet from keras:

```python
base_model = DenseNet169(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
```

set trainable to False for it's layers and add those heads in a following manner:

```python
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
psi = Dense(256, activation = 'softmax')(x)
```

Unfortunately that doesn't converge at all: validation error just grow unbounded while training. I'm quite sure about training data, so my current theory is that heads should be a little more complicated.

Does anybody implement that paper or have an idea of what those heads should look like?

Comment: Probably  you should include a dropout layer

Comment: Hi Alex, were you ever able to come up with a working implementation? I am interested as well